# Can't login admin panel 1.9.2 after clean var/session

Tags: admin-login

I worked hard at my website (mag community), but now i can't login in the admin panel.
I want to know if there is a simple solution to solve this problem.
After i deleted all session from var/session, it works once, but now i have the same problem.

Please, any advices ?
Thanks,
silver

Comment: Can you describe your server setup?

Comment: Hello, thank you, here is the PhP setting:  Register Globals: On,
Safe Mode: Off,
Magic Quotes: On,
Upload Max Filesize: 15,
POST Max Size: 15,  
Ioncube: Off,
Zend: Off, Upload Max Filesize: 32 Mb.

Comment: Do you see just a blank page or can you see the login screen? If the latter, what happens when you type your `username` and `password` and click the login button? Does the page refresh or do you get a blank screen? What browser are you using? Have you tried using other browsers, clearing all browser cache and cookies? Please update your question with answers to those questions. It will make it much easier for the community to try and help you.

Comment: cookies issue might be.. try increasing cookies time..

Comment: Thank you, i can type the user/password and nothing is happening. I use mozilla, but i tried also explorer and opera. The number of files from var/sessions, increase. Also, i clean up the cash, cookies from mozilla, but nothing. I repeat, the website works very well until now.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser used? If chrome it may happened. For this first take another browser and go to admin check the `system->configuration->web->session & cookie management` in that  the `http control` set from `Yes` to `No`.

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

It could have something to do with the session storage. Try to save sessions to the database instead.

Open `app/etc/local.xml` and change

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

To

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmi, my http is "no", last time when i could login. regarding the data base, i'm afraid to not damage the database. If there is other solution, it will be perfect. i use mozilla.

Comment: could i damage something at my website, if i deleted the sesions fron var/sesions ?

Comment: Not really, at worst you will kill any logged in users in front end or back end and potentially delete the contents of shopping carts, but no permanent damage.  [More details in related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353875/how-long-do-the-magento-session-files-need-to-be-kept).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by modify the core_config_data from database, i set:
Cookies.path     = '/';
Cookies.domain   = 'example.com';

But now, i face with other issue, after i deleted the cache.
My shipping settings have changed and i can't set only one country in the estimate shipping cost (on the front page).
My default country is Romania, but the country field from checkout is empty and i can't estimate the shipping cost.
I use magento 1.9.2